# How do I delete a row with a null foreign key using Linq-to-SQL?

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq-to-sql, foreign-keys, nullable

I have a table called `tblOvrdImpVolsType` with two foreign key columns that are both nullable.  I'm having trouble deleting a row in this table using Linq-To-SQL when one of the foreign key columns in this row is null.  Here's my code:

```
using (Databases.Global db = new Databases.Global())
{
    db.Log = Console.Out;
    var records = from iv in db.tblOvrdImpVolsType
                    join sm in db.tblSecurityMasterType 
                       on iv.FkSecurity equals sm.PkSecurity
                    where sm.Name == name
                    select iv; //returns only 1 record

    db.tblOvrdImpVolsType.DeleteAllOnSubmit<MyTableType>(records);

    int numDeletes = db.GetChangeSet().Deletes.Count; // = 1
    db.SubmitChanges(); //deletes 0 records
}
```

- Databases.Global inherits from DataContext and has the tables that I use.
- tblOvrdImpVolsType has two nullable, foreign key columns (key1 and key2)
- the row I am interested has these key values (key1 = 9898, key2 = null)
- In my C# code, the datatypes of key1 and key2 are both `int?` and `CanBeNull = true`
- The `GetChangeSet()` shows that one record will be deleted, but when I check the database, that row is clearly not deleted.
- No exceptions are thrown.

Here is the SQL that the DataContext generates:

```
DELETE FROM [tblOvrdImpVols] WHERE ([key1] = @p0) AND ([key2] = @p1)
-- @p0: Input Int (Size = -1; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [9898]
-- @p1: Input Int (Size = -1; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [Null]
-- Context: SqlProvider(Sql2008) Model: AttributedMetaModel Build: 4.0.30319.17929
```

I think the problem is the `[key2] = @p1` part.  Because the key2 value I'm interested in is null, the SQL is bad.  These SQL queries below illustrate this.  The only difference is the `is` vs. `=` in the `key2` condition:

```
select * FROM [tblOvrdImpVols] WHERE ([key1] = 9898) AND ([key2] is null)
    --returns 1 row

select * FROM [tblOvrdImpVols] WHERE ([key1] = 9898) AND ([key2] = null)
    --returns 0 rows
```

What am I doing wrong?  I assume that if I can get the DataContext object to replace the `=` with `is` for null values, the deletes will work.  I don't know how to do that.  I also assume this question has been asked before, but I can't find it.

EDIT: I originally called my keys "primary" rather than "foreign".  I meant to say "foreign".  I edited my post to say "foreign" instead.  I am still having the same problem.

Comment: As far as I know, SQL Server does **not allow** any of the columns of a primary key to be nullable. No idea how you managed to get this up and running - I believe it basically should not be doable at all....

Comment: Can you generate a script for the table so we can see what you mean by "nullable primary key"?

Comment: Not to mention being altogether crazy to try.

Comment: Crap, I meant to say foreign key.  In my code `key1` and `key2` are both foreign keys, not primary keys.  My mistake.

Comment: I think your database model must be wrong and have Key1 and Key2 marked with the IsPrimaryKey attribute.

Comment: I accidentally typed "primary key" when I meant to type "foreign key".  I edited my post yesterday to fix this error.  Neither `Key1` nor `Key2` is marked with the `IsPrimaryKey` attribute.  This is not a question about a database model.  This is a question about deleting a row when one of its columns is null.

Comment: The way DeleteAllOnSubmit in Linq-to-Sql works is by performing a select statement and then deleting each record individually by using the primarykey, ie doing a 'delete from table where primarykey=@p0' or 'delete from table where primarykey1=@p0 and primarykey2=@p1' etc. Hence, the only way for the Linq-to-Sqql delete command to issue the sql you quote, is if the c# class generated by your model has both key1 and key2 marked as your primary key.

Answer (score 0):

To make sure that you also catch nulls, you could modify your query to look like this :

```
select * FROM [tblOvrdImpVols] 
WHERE ([key1] = @p0) AND 
([key2] = @p1 OR 
    ([key2] is null and @p1 is null) )
```

Answer (score 0):

The main problem here - in SQL, nothing is equal to NULL. NULL is not equal even to itself! "NULL = NULL" will evaluate to "false" in SQL query. So, when you need to delete rows where [key2] == null, you need to write LINQ query which will produce SQL like

"WHERE [key2] = @p1 AND [key2] IS NULL"

instead of

"WHERE [key2] = @p1 AND [key2] = @p2".

How to do it? It seems the right way will be to compare [key2] with null.
For example, if you want to get all rows from tblSecurityMasterType where Name is NULL, this will be the wrong way:

```
string NameNull = null;
from sm in db.tblSecurityMasterType 
     where sm.Name == NameNull
     select sm;
```

You will need to use this query instead:

```
from sm in db.tblSecurityMasterType 
     where sm.Name == null
     select sm;
```

It's described here: http://smsohan.com/blog/2008/08/05/comparing-with-null-in-where-clause-in/